# Why does discord keep sending requests to my server weirdly

Tags: server, python-requests, discord

I am doing a simple imaging service (related to a game called Transformice), which would listen to requests, then load and grab XML of "maps" from the game, generate the image and then serve that image to the client. This project is open sourced so you may find the code [here](https://github.com/Seniru/tfm-tools)

It works fine so far when I request an image from the browser, but when I tried to load the same thing in discord, it sends lots of requests to me in an unexpected way.

I did some loggings so it's easier to understand what's actually happening.

```
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/589352/preview <200> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/589352/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Discordbot/2.0; +https://discordapp.com))
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/999999/preview <200> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Discordbot/2.0; +https://discordapp.com))
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/999999/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/999999/preview <200> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)

[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/123455/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Discordbot/2.0; +https://discordapp.com))
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/999999/preview <200> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/696969/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/424242/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/696969/preview <200> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <200> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/424242/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/424242/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/424242/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/424242/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/42069/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Discordbot/2.0; +https://discordapp.com))
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/424242/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/777777/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/424242/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/69420/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Discordbot/2.0; +https://discordapp.com))
[INFO][SERVER|MAIN] GET /map/999999/preview <-> (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)
```

First I requested from browser (the first log) and it worked fine, after I tried to load the same thing in discord, few worked but then it kept doing this - requesting the same resource infinitely. Because of this there are some delays and sometimes it doesn't load the map at all.

What I wanted to know is the exact reason for this behaviour and a way to handle this kinds of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the `Discordbot/2.0` user agent:

This is Discord loading the HTML file in an effort to find certain metadata inside the `<head>` tag, like [OpenGraph](https://ogp.me/) and [Twitter Cards](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/getting-started), that it needs for building an embed preview when a link to one of your webpages gets posted.

However, once the data has been scraped, it gets cached inside Discord's servers for some time, which is why you'll only see one request per a unique URL from this user agent. (See [this thesis](https://www.cs.ru.nl/bachelors-theses/2021/Stefan_Popa___1027672___You_Have_Been_Previewed_-_Information_Leaks_of_Content_Previews_in_Mobile_Messengers.pdf#subsection.5.2.1) for a bit more info about the requests themselves.)

I'm not sure what could be causing the large amount of requests from the `Macintosh` user agent, though. Maybe it could be something with content types and the way you handle request responses in your `app/handler.js`?